# Working ASN.1 Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, asn.1

Any recommendations for ASN.1 Eclipse plugin that actually works ?

So far I've tried ASN lab which freezes on sufficiently large files and objective systems which sometimes gives cryptic exceptions and sometimes fails for other reasons which are hard to understand.

Comment: Have you tried [ASN.1 Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asneditor/)?

Comment: Yes. It shows errors on perfectly correct ASN.1 code from S1AP standard.